# How to uninstall specific versions of Postgres?

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

On Ubuntu 14.04 I have done this to get the latest postgres:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then I installed version 9.4:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

However it seems I have now three versions:

```
sudo service postgresql stop

 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server  [ OK ]
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.4 database server  [ OK ]
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.5 database server  [ OK ]
```

How can I keep only 9.4 and uninstall the other ones?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

As suggested in comments I have uninstalled 9.3 and 9.5.

But when I do this:

```
sudo service postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5432): down
9.4/main (port 5434): online
9.5/main (port 5433): down
```

So far so good, but when I switch to postgres:

```
sudo su postgres
```

and do a psql, I get an error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: How did you install 9.3 and 9.5?

Comment: 9.3 was installed by default in 14.04.  9.5 was installed the moment I added the PPI above.  It just installed the latest server.

Comment: Postgres is not part of a default Ubuntu ;-) But then I would assume `sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3` will remove 9.3 (after shutting down the 9.3 server)

Comment: Thanks I followed your advice, please see updated question.

Comment: I found it.  The solution is to purge everything as it says here: http://askubuntu.com/a/334730/58150

Answer (score 13):

Different versions of PostgreSQL are located in the packages postgresql-9.*.

1. So you should remove your two packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.3 postgresql-9.5
   ```
2. Then you should remove unnecessary config folders:

   ```
   rm -r /etc/postgresql/9.3/ /etc/postgresql/9.5
   ```
3. And from /var/lib/ folder if you have:

   ```
   /var/lib/postgresql/*
   ```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Good answer!  5 years later, the "purge" step optionally removes the `/etc/` components.  for you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding answer very late but might help people here.

**Short answer:** Error indicates postgres configured on wrong(not default) port. Use the right port

**Long answer:** 
When you installed multiple version of Postgresql, all of them started running postgres clusters on different port. In your output, following postgres versions are running: `9.3 --> 5432`, `9.4 -->5434`, `9.5 --> 5433`.

```
sudo service postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5432): down
9.4/main (port 5434): online
9.5/main (port 5433): down
```

You can uninstall the other versions using `sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.x` where `9.x` is your version however in your case the version(9.4) which was present on your system is configured to run on port 5434. Thus the error `Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?` perfectly indicates that psql by default trying to connect to port `5432` which no longer has any postgres attached.

**Two solutions here**:

- Either use `psql -p 5434` i.e port option(-p/--port) in psql command.
- Or configure your postgres server `port` configuration value in `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` to serve on 5432. Don't forget to restart postgres after change.