# How to correctly enable Postgresql on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, postgresql

I installed psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1. When I type

```
psql
```

I got:

```
 psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I type

```
netstat -ln
```

I got the following:

```
  Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::10137                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::20080                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39111           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::56552                :::*                               
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7
```

showing I got no 5432 port available. I tried using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432) but got nothing. I tried the same method using postgres 9.4 and 9.6 but I got nothing different too. Anyone has any tips to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a look at this one?  There might be a few permissions errors: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285080/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't manage to accomplish this. The only way out was installing by compiling the binaries and so on. With this method everything worked